# Ошибка в обрезании фото PHP

Tags: php

С новыми стандартами переделываю обрезание фото, но оно выдаёт ошибки. Пути проверял несколько раз, и относительные ставил и абсолютные, и напрямую путь подкидывал, но без успешно(
В базу записывается.

```
 // ОБРЕЗАТЬ ФОТО И СОХРАНИТЬ
if(($task=="new_crop") AND ($insert) AND ($id==$sender) AND ($cmd=="6")){
$img        = $users->get_post_data('big');
$room_id    = intval($users->get_post_data('room_id'));
$album      = intval($users->get_post_data('album'));


$file_width = $users->get_post_data('w');   
$file_height = $users->get_post_data('h');
    
$x1 = $users->get_post_data('x1');  
$y1 = $users->get_post_data('y1');  


$cn_foto = md5(date('Y-M-D-h-m-s'));
$big = "users_alb/$sender/big/".$cn_foto.".jpg";
$thumb = "users_alb/$sender/thumb/".$cn_foto.".jpg";

// START WEBP ФОТО
$webp_big           = "users_alb/$sender/webp_big/".$cn_foto.".webp";
$webp_thumb         = "users_alb/$sender/webp_thumb/".$cn_foto.".webp";
// END WEBP ФОТО


if($file_width > $file_height){
$out_height = ($file_width / $foto_big_size);
$width = $foto_big_size;
$height = ($file_height / $out_height);
}else{
$out_width = ($file_height / $foto_big_size);
$height = $foto_big_size;
$width = ($file_width / $out_width);
}

$w = $width;
$h = $height;

//print "$x1, $y1, $width, $height, $file_width, $file_height";


$file = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
$new = imagecreatefromjpeg($img);//313 строчка    
imagecopyresampled($file, $new, 0, 0, $x1, $y1, $width, $height, $file_width, $file_height);
imagejpeg($file, $big, 100);
ImageDestroy($new);
ImageDestroy($file);

$file = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
$new = imagecreatefromjpeg($img);     
imagecopyresampled($file, $new, 0, 0, $x1, $y1, $width, $height, $file_width, $file_height);
imagejpeg($file, $thumb, 100);
ImageDestroy($new);
ImageDestroy($file);

$file = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
$new = imagecreatefromjpeg($img);     
imagecopyresampled($file, $new, 0, 0, $x1, $y1, $width, $height, $file_width, $file_height);
imagewebp($file, $webp_big, 100);
ImageDestroy($new);
ImageDestroy($file);

$file = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
$new = imagecreatefromjpeg($img);     
imagecopyresampled($file, $new, 0, 0, $x1, $y1, $width, $height, $file_width, $file_height);
imagewebp($file, $webp_thumb, 100);//335 строчка
ImageDestroy($new);
ImageDestroy($file);
```

Вот какие ошибки приходят:
[image: errors]

Comment: я не силён, для меня не понятно как решить это, в базу пишутся фото и jpg и webp форматы, а отображаются webp если современные браузеры

Comment: `var_dump($img);` что показывает?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function var_dum()

Comment: показал string(59) "users_alb/36/webp_big/4d5dd8cb78cd66c2f065241b2059f1ea.webp"

Comment: Странно.. а `var_dump($users->get_post_data('big'));`?

Comment: то же самое string(59) "users_alb/36/webp_big/4d5dd8cb78cd66c2f065241b2059f1ea.webp"

Comment: но когда захожу в альбом фото становится чёрным, вместо того чтобы обрезать

Comment: Ну вот и ошибка, собственно. 313 строка `$new = imagecreatefromjpeg($img);` ожидает jpeg, а у вас изначально загружается webp

Comment: буду копать, вписал $new = imagecreatefromwebp($img); решило много ошибок

Comment: Со smarty не знаком, поэтому чем смог. Удачи

Comment: Спасибо всё решилось) фотка изменяет размер